# ¿Por qué esta comunicación Python - PHP - Python funciona en con un router y con otro no?

Tags: python, python-3.x, php7, apache2, raspberry-pi

**Antecedentes:**
En la raspberry **A** tengo el siguiente script Python:

```
 import httplib2

  http = httplib2.Http()
  content = http.request("http://192.168.0.123/exe.php", method="GET",
                  headers={'user-agent': 'Python script'})[1] 
  print(content.decode())
```

En el localhost de la raspberry **B** (IP: 192.168.0.123) tengo el script exe.php

```
<?PHP

    exec('python comando.py');
    echo 'Ok';

?>
```

y ademas (obviamente) el script comando.py que genera un archivo txt con un 'hola mundo'.

**Problema:**
Tengo una red creada con un router de una casa X y todo funciona perfecto, es decir:

1. Al ejecutar el script Python de la Raspberry **A**
2. Se llama al archivo exe.php que se encuentra en http://192.168.0.123/exe.php
3. El exe.php ejecuta el archivo comando.py

Pero lo extraño, y lo que me hizo finalmente crear esta pregunta, es que al cambiar todo esto a una casa Z, todo sucede bien a excepción de la ejecución de comando.py. Es decir , se logra la comunicación, se que se ejecuta el PHP (me retorna el ok del echo) pero no se ejecuta el python del servidor. Al volver a la casa X todo vuelve a funcionar.

Una de las possible conclusiones es que el router de la casa X no tenga configurado los permisos adecuados pero ¿Qué tendría que ver si la comunicación se concreta?. Está demás decir que las raspberry son las mismas, las ip son acorde a la nueva conexión y que solo cambia el router.

Comment: Entiendo que para deducir que no se ejecutó el script `comando.py` te basarás en el fichero `archivo.txt` que debería aparecer. ¿no habrás cambiado algún permiso en la carpeta al ir de una casa a otra? Puedes mirar los logs de php en busca de alguna pista mas. Como dices, no parece que el router tenga nada qué ver si el php llega a ejecutarse.

Comment: Claro debe aparecer un 'archivo.txt' y claro ya descartamos que la carpeta no tenga permisos de escritura por que al regresar el sistema a casa , todo vuelve a funcionar. Pensamos que puede ser el router porque la conexión  es de la U y puede que tenga algunos puertos cerrados , pero no debería ser el caso ya que los archivos se comunican igual.